# Python sliding window for images to be used in CNN

Tags: python, package, conv-neural-network, sliding-window

This is something that I'm sure there must be a package out there for, but for the  life of me I can not find it.

I've trained a CNN with a given size image looking for heads and then wish to give it a larger image to look within for the heads. Now the way this is typically done is a *sliding window*, a sub image is made from the larger image,  and then we slide the bounding box of the sub image through the larger image, often with significant overlap (maybe 50%). Also since the thing I'm looking for might be bigger or smaller than in the training data I need to start with a huge bounding box (say 3 times the size of the training images) scale it down to the training size, slide over the image, then try again with something 2.5x the size, then  2, 1.5,1,0.75,0.5,0.25  etc.

It's not too complicated for me to write on my lonesome, but my implementation will be slow and messy. There must be an python package that does this. What's it called?!

Comment: Somebody else may be able to correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe such a module exists. But there are plenty of examples out there that would be easy enough to adapt. [Here](https://github.com/adventuresinML/adventures-in-ml-code/blob/master/convolutional_neural_network_tutorial.py), for example, or TensorFlow's own [CNN example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn).